# pymongo outer left join by lookup + search by regex

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pydantic

I have 2 collections and I want to search all users by regular expression but only return `users` that don't exist in `views`.

```
/* Users */
{
    "user_id" : "SB4mKAxaBijQXnS73",
    "username" : "user1"
},
{
    "user_id" : "SB4mdasd3ijQXnS73",
    "username" : "user2"
}

/* Views */
{
     "view_id " : "rhqioBkePzGCrRFLp",
     "recipient_username" : "user1"
 }
```

I'm using beanie, so function has to be async and collection is called from pydantic classes `User` and `View`.

UPDATED:
My code so far:

```
        user = await User.aggregate([
                            {'$lookup':
                                {
                                    'from': View.get_collection_name(),
                                    'localField': "username",
                                    'foreignField': "recipient_username",
                                    'let': { "username": "username", "recipient_username": "username"},
                                    'pipeline': [{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$username", "$$username" ] }}}}],
                                    'as': 'out'
                                }}]).to_list()
    return user
```

My pipeline does not properly evaluate my expression. Any idea why?

Comment: You should use [aggregate](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/aggregation.html) instead of find?

Comment: Also, refer the documentation for proper usage of the [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) syntax. Also, avoid using the variable names with a dot in it (`User.username` ), as the dot has a special meaning in MongoDB queries.

Comment: @ray thanks, synta now seems to work but still a problem with the pipeline expression. It does not evaluate my condition, I simply get a list of all users without excluding the ones that exist in `View`. Do you know why?

Comment: You could be looking for [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eioUZ2httxw). You are mixing up the variables in the `let` clause. And `$in` should not be used like this. It should be used only for array expressions.

Comment: @ray thanks a lot, this literally saved me! Got everything working now. Maybe add it as n answer so I can upvote and mark as correct. Super helpful thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for confirming first. But sorry that I need to vote to close the question as the root cause is just incorrect usage of syntax.